# AWS EC2: cannot get bare metal instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bare-metal

I have tried several times in the last two weeks to log on to a c5.metal instance.  Each time I get "Initializing" in the status checks field, but after 10 minutes it is still "Initializing" and I'm not able to log on.  I have had success with c5.metal before, but not any more.

Today I also tried to get an m5.metal instance.  This time the instance successfully initialized after 10 minutes but I was not able to log on with Putty.  I stopped the instance, then after about 30 minutes I tried again and this time I did not get past "Initializing" in the status check field and I stopped it after 15 minutes.

I get billed for the 10 to 15 minute bare metal wait periods, even when initialization doesn't complete.  I have no problems with AWS virtual instances.

Thanks for any ideas on what I can do to get the bare metal instances to work.

Comment: Have you contented AWS support? It seems like a good question for them.

Comment: Which Region, AZ and AMI are you selecting? I can attempt to reproduce.

Comment: @John Rotenstein - Ubuntu 18.04 in AWS Ohio datacenter (us-east-2c).

Comment: @RTC222 Please drop me an email (see my profile) so we can figure out your c5.metal issue.

Comment: Thanks very much, John.  I'll email you tomorrow morning (I'm in Seattle, so US Pacific time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Launched an Amazon EC2 instance in Ohio:

  - Instance Type: `c5.metal`
  - AMI: *Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type*
  - Network: In my *Default VPC* so that it uses a Public Subnet
  - Security Group: Default settings, which grants port 22 access from the Internet
- Instance entered **running** state very quickly, Status Checks showed as **Initializing**

It took about 8 minutes until the status checks were showing `2/2 checks` (it might have been faster, but I was testing other things in the meantime).

I was able to successfully login to the instance:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1065-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Sat Jun  6 23:21:18 UTC 2020

  System load:  0.02              Processes:               924
  Usage of /:   13.7% of 7.69GB   Users logged in:         0
  Memory usage: 0%                IP address for enp125s0: 172.31.9.77
  Swap usage:   0%

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.



The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-77:~$
```

(Actually, I first tried to login as `ec2-user` and it took me a while to realize this was an Ubuntu AMI, so I connected as `ubuntu`).

It is possible that the slow startup is due to the Operating System or hardware checking the 192GB of RAM that is allocated to the instance.

I booted another instance using an **Amazon Linux 2** AMI and it required approximately 7 minutes before I could connect.

I also noticed that the c5.metal instances did not provide anything for "Get System Log" or "Get Instance Screenshot". This might be a result of using a bare-metal instance.

Comment: Thanks, John -- that's very helpful.  You did some things I did not do, so I will use this as a guide when I log on to bare metal soon.

Answer (score 1):

I joined John Rotenstein's twitch.tv channel and he showed how he got a c5.metal instance.  What I learned is that if a metal instance does not work in the region you had chosen, try launching a new instance in a different data center region.  For example, I had a c5.metal instance at us-east-2a.  Following John's directions, I launched an instance at us-east-2c and after about 8 minutes the instance was ready for use.