# AWS EC2: cannot get bare metal instance - update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Yesterday I posted a question about my problems getting a bare metal instance at AWS ( [AWS EC2: cannot get bare metal instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237991/aws-ec2-cannot-get-bare-metal-instance)).  An AWS Technical Evangelist answered with instructions on how he was able to log on to a bare metal instance.

Today I followed those directions on a c5.metal instance, and after 12 minutes I got 1/2 checks with a yellow triangle with an exclamation point (meaning something is wrong -- the correct display is 2/2 checks).  Needless to say I could not long on with Putty.

As I said in my question yesterday, I have had repeated problems recently getting AWS bare metal instances to initialize so I can log on.  I get billed for these failed attempts.

I don't have any problems with AWS virtual instances, but a lot of problems recently with the bare metal instances.

Thanks very much for any ideas on how I can get a bare metal instance at AWS to complete its status checks and allow me to log on.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like something that the AWS Support should be able help you with. You can open a support ticket directly from the AWS Management Console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home

Comment: AWS will only answer the question if I subscribe for support at $30 per month, which I'm not willing to do just for this.  I hoped that AWS would at least use my report to see what's wrong but so far that hasn't happened.

Comment: Why do you think you need to have plan for support?. They cleary write: Basic Support is included for **all AWS customers** and includes. The payed plans are for some faster and extra help, not for asking why their service does not work as it should.

Comment: AWS support has already told me they will not answer this question without a support subscription.

Comment: What about basic troubleshooting> Changing region, or using different account if you have access to one?